# Access 2010 report ignores filter placed on it

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I have run into an error with an Access Database created in MS-Access 2003.  It's known the Calendar Control was deprecated in Access 2010 but unfortunately we need to keep using it.  As a temp fix (until we can change to the date picker) we restored the MSCAL.OCX file on all 2010 users.

**The issue:**

We have a form to print schedules from a date range (using the calendar control).  There is some VBA code to check to dates etc to make sure the range is accurate etc.

Everything works fine in 2003 but in 2010 the dates get selected fine on the form, is passed to the report (a print preview) fine as it displays in the footer **BUT the query ignores the date range and prints ALL records (not just the records in the date range).**

Is there any way I can step into Print Preview button when clicked to see what's being passed?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the filter not being applied to the report is a known Microsoft issue with certain set ups of Windows 7 and Access 2010.  The hotfix found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596496 solved my problem.

I run Windows 7 64 bit and Office 2010 32 bit, when downloading the hotfix I selected the "x86" platform as that's the 32 bit. If you are using Office 2010 64 bit you should download the "x64" platform.

To find out your office version, open any office product, click File Tab, click Help and it will be on the right under "About Microsoft ".

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can really do that is if your report/query is running some VBA code and put a Stop on the the VBA.

If your query is referencing the fields directly (IMNSHO a bad practice, but I'll work with what we've got) you could change them so they instead reference a VBA function that returns the results of those fields instead. Then you know what it is getting for sure.

Comment: It's really weird, the VBA for the Print Preview button is running OpenReport (acViewPreview) that's it.  How does it know what to query?  I've looked into the button properties and it's just running [Event Procedure] on click.  Is there somewhere else it could be referencing the report? (As you can see I inherited this DB) - thanks for helping

Comment: It's probably being called directly in the query then, have a look at in SQL view. Here's an example of how I've called a function from a query that might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716014/why-do-sql-queries-with-vba-function-run-so-slow

Comment: I found it - 'DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSchedule", iOpenMode, , strWhereCon' strWhereCon passes through the group and dates to a report. The report then queries the database...I am going to try the SQL view now as it has to be in there.  I see the info being passed but once passed to the report that's it. Must be somewhere in the query.

Comment: It's the query for sure, we have one for a one day report and the variable passes the same way and it works fine.  Is there any way to step into the query or right before it?  I just can't figure out why it's showing the whole table but for the 1 day it shows the single day.

Comment: can you post the queries associated with the reports? Anonymise them a little if the table/column names are sensitive.

Comment: The query is: SELECT tblTable1.SomeName, tblTable2.txtGrpID, tblTable2.dateStart, tblTable2.timeStart, tblTable2.dateStop, tblTable2.timeStop, [Doc Data Table].[Last Name], [Doc Data Table].[First Name], tblTable2.lDocID, [First Name] & " " & [Last Name] AS TidyName
FROM tblTable1 INNER JOIN (tblTable2 INNER JOIN [Doc Data Table] ON tblTable2.lDocID = [Doc Data Table].[Unique ID]) ON tblTable1.[Something Group] = tblTable2.txtGrpID
ORDER BY Table2.dateStart, Table2.timeStart;

Comment: The variable being passed through the VBA from the form is: txtGrpID = "3" AND dateStart >= 41699 AND dateStart <= 41729   I changed the table names.  The VBA passes that variable to the report, then report then calls the query as seen above in SQL.  Thanks a ton :)

Comment: It'll have to be something to do with the contents of strWhereCon. It really should be more explicit about the name (tblTable2.dateStart) just in case tblTable1 also has a dateStart in it too.

Comment: CodeSlave you've been a great help!  Finally resolved the issue, after folowing all the advice I realized it had to be working...it just didn't make sense.  I called Microsoft and what do you know, there is an issue with certain setups where Access 2010 doesn't apply filters to reports.  There is a simple hotfix which solved my issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596496

Answer (score 0):

There is one more trick that surely worked out for me as a solution, before I came across the accepted answer about hotfix on this thread. Also, because, the hotfix link leads to a valid thread, but there are not downloadable files.

The workaround:

Make a copy of the report file. Use that name in VBA under DoCmd call. Strange how it works, though. Such is the nature of bugs, I guess.